# Saving jpg to file messes it up

Tags: android, bitmap, save

When I save and load a jpg image (with a white background) to external storage, it looks like this:

[image]

The code:

Save:

```
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("cache", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Load:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.toString());
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The original image has a white background and it doesn't look messed up.

Comment: may be it will helps you `Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(image);
  comboImage.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
  comboImage.translate(0, 0);`

Comment: translate as far I know is space (dx, dy), not color. And anyways, what it 0, 0 supposed to do? And if what you mean is change black color of the image to white, I don't want to change originally black areas to white...

Comment: I guess the original black colors will not be disturbed. The `outStream` you are making from a `png or bmp` image? which have transparent areas.

Comment: From a jpg image. And I still don't understand how and why your approach with canvas would help.

Comment: In my case when I am drawing the `bmp` images on canvas, I also have same problem. But `comboImage.drawColor(Color.WHITE);` solve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use (should work for you):

Save Bitmap:

```
public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to the OutputStream
        try {
            fos = game.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

And to read:

```
public Bitmap readBitmapFromMemory(String filename) {
        Bitmap defautBitmap = null;
        File filePath = game.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        FileInputStream fi;
        try {
            fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            defautBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return defautBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: The only difference I see to my code is that you use `outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` instead of `outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);`, I don't think that's messing up the pixel data of the bitmap.

Comment: It allows me to read JPEG files, not sure if it will work and if yes why, but you should give it a try.